# addthis: JS security error for addthis utility frame

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, addthis

I'm trying to use addthis on my page. When using Chrome, I receive a JavaScript security error.

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL <AddThis url> from frame with URL <local url>. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

The only frame I've got in this page is an AddThis-generated one, with the title "AddThis utility frame".

Is there any way to get over this?

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this in addthis's implementation of nucaptcha for their version 250. Try upgrading to their 300 version, they went back to recaptcha.